# UITableViewCell not showing background and insets after reloadSections

Tags: ios, swift, xib, ios14

In my UITableView I have implemented an expandable sections behaviour: If a cell of index 0 within a section is clicked, the rest of this section is shown by doing

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        isSectionExpanded[indexPath.section] = !isSectionExpanded[indexPath.section]
        tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none)
    }
}
```

I naively have an array of booleans where I keep track of the "expanded"-state of each section:

```
var isSectionExpanded = [Bool]()
```

The number of rows in a section therefore is calculated like this (there is one row for the "header" and one for the "footer", in addition to one row for each leg in a trip:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let trip = trips?[section] {
        if isSectionExpanded[section] {
            return 2 + (trip.legs?.count ?? 0)
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

Quite simple, and it all worked well, and it still does on iOS 12 for example. But on recent versions of iOS - unfortunately I don't know when this started, maybe iOS 14.1 or 2 - the expanded cells don't have any background and do not draw the insets anymore. Looking for help I saw a few posts which refer to similar problems, but using SwiftUI. I still use xib-files and Swift.
I already tried setting the background on the Content View, which correctly shows the background, but the insets are still missing...
I even tried loading the content by using `reloadData()`: again, this shows the background of the cell, but not the insets. And of course the animation is lost..

[Screenshot on iOS 12.5 (displaying correctly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPcTU.png)

[Screenshot on iOS 14.4 (missing background and insets)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1OCk.png)

When some of these cells is clicked, the correct background color is drawn with a strange animation from top left to bottom right.

Can anyone tell me what is causing this issue and how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem now, and it has nothing to do with the iOS version:
Recently in this custom cell view class, I've overridden `layoutSubviews()`, but without calling `super.layoutSubviews()`. Once I added this, all worked fine again!

Answer (score 0):

iOS 12 is using white color - background default color.
iOS 14 is using group tableview color - background default color.
you can see these in Xcode 10.3 and Xcode 11.x
Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't understand... Those system colors were introduced in iOS 13, to support dark mode, right? And all worked fine before. BTW, also in dark mode the issues are the same as described above.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I think whenever you reload sections (number of Rowsin Section) function is not working, it can be reset after reload tableview.